# “Lost connection to MySQL server during query” error

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I have MySQL 5.5.20 and this table:

```
mysql> desc country;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id             | int(255)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| iso            | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name           | varchar(80) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| printable_name | varchar(80) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| iso3           | varchar(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numcode        | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

If I run a query like this

```
SELECT country.ID, country.ISO, country.NAME,
   country.PRINTABLE_NAME, country.ISO3, country.NUMCODE
FROM country;
```

It returns:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

If I change the order of the columns (ISO3 before PRINTABLE_NAME for example) like this:

```
SELECT country.ID, country.ISO, country.NAME,
   country.PRINTABLE_NAME,  country.NUMCODE, country.ISO3
FROM country;
```

It works fine!

Or if I rewrite the query using lower-case letters for columns, it works as well.

This issue appears from time to time (about once a month) and the only solution to fix it is to restart MySQL! i have checked error log and this what i have in it:

```
130310 11:01:23 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 401108  user: 'root'
```

I am really confused and don't know why this happens! Any ideas on how this could be fixed?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you check the MySQL bug database?

Comment: Yes, But didn't find any help !

Comment: The first major search engine result for your error message went to here: http://www.justskins.com/forums/error-2013-hy000-lost-131977.html where the person was able to solve it.

Comment: @Aiias: this shouldn't fix the problem,,, innodb_force_recovery should be used when you have a problem with innodb table, but in this case the table is working fine, coz he can get the result if he changes the case (to lower) or change the order of columns in the select statement